# VSCode and Anaconda Environments: How to have dev extensions/environment and my code under development use different Anaconda environments

Tags: python, anaconda, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, many extensions, such as Tab Nine and Lint, rely on specific Python packages to function. On the other hand, the code I develop may need a different set of packages. Because there is the potential for package conflict and because we want the environment that we develop code to mimic the production environment,  it is convenient to have the dev environment/extensions use one Anaconda Environment and the code I develop to use a different Anaconda Environment. But I am not sure how to configure this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Down in the bottom left corner of VS code you can manually select the python environment depending on which codebase you are working with. The selection can be saved in the settings.json file so you don't have to manually reselect each time.

Comment: Yes, I know this. My problem is that I would like the extensions that serve VSCode editor/debugger, etc. to use one set of packages from one environment but my code base to use a different set of packages from a different environment, for the sake of better separation and less interference.

Comment: I see, two environments working in parallel so to speak? That's beyond my knowledge but it may well be possible

Comment: MIght be possible to do something like that by creating a new env, with multiple versions of any given package, and each version being renamed into its own namespace somehow. That could be awkward for more than a few packages though.